# DEOptim Variable Constraint - force one variable to be lower than the other

Tags: r, variables, optimization

I'm using DEOptim package in R and it works as intended for my purpose but I'd like for one variable to always be lower than the other (I'm optimising a moving average strategy). I can't seem to figure out how to do this, does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code showing what you already tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I wouldn't know where to start. Basically DEOptim is optimisating over 2 variables (let's called them A and B). Since it's a moving average strategy, I'd like for the fast moving average A to always be a lower value than the slow moving average B. Where in the syntax do I enter that as a constraint?